# Using double value as a score for GKLeaderboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, gamekit

I wondered if there's a way of using a double value on `GKLeaderboard`? It insists that I use `int64_t`, but I need double values to be used, as the leaderboard is for the fastest time, counting to six decimal points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need a decimal number down to the millions, one solution would be to simply multiply by 1,000,000 and coerce to an `int64_t`:

```
int64_t intScore = (int64_t)1000000 * doubleScore;
```

Then when you get the score back:

```
double doubleScore = (double)intScore / 1000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're measuring with microsecond precision, you can just have the units be microseconds instead of seconds. Then you can use integers.

(Similarly, money should never be represented as a floating-point value, but as an integral value representing the smallest amount of money you want to consider — so a dollar would be 100 (cents) rather than 1.0 (dollars).)